# Track the copy/paste via filesystem driver

Tags: c, windows, winapi, driver, smb

Is there a way to track the directory and name of the files copied/moved **from** the network drive (e.g. SMB mapped to drive letter) to the local one, via Windows WDK, minifilter driver or by any other means? What I found is that the possible mechanism might rely on I/O request packets, such as `IRP_MJ_CREATE` or `IRP_MJ_WRITE`.

Even if I filter every transaction, I am unable to extract the information of the source folder/drive. Is there something I miss?

Comment: impossible get information about source folder/drive

Comment: @RbMm Thanks. Does it mean that the only way is to implement a sort of file database on both machines, and compare something (e.g. hash) when the file operation occurs? Any tips/suggestions?

Comment: this ( "compare something" ) very problematic too, because not exist "file operation" as atomic action. need begin from - what your real target

Comment: @RbMm The goal is to detect the copy of files from the network drive.

Comment: in practic this is impossible

Comment: Copy/paste is a feature of the Shell (i.e. explorer.exe). Down-stream system comments don't know anything about that.

Comment: @IInspectable What if the copy is performed via another file manager (e.g. Total Commander, Far Manager, anything else)? I guess there is no way to know **the source** for sure, in this case.

Comment: Total Commander (and Far Manager probably, too) use the Shell API to implement copy/paste operations, at least across processes. The important point here is, that once the I/O stack gets involved, there's no notion of anything that would resemble a "copy" or "paste" operation any more. It's just I/O read and write requests, where read requests generally don't know that they are the source for a subsequent I/O write request.